# Type argument interference doesn't work, but explicit type argument does

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've came across a peculiar issue when trying to implement generic types. Let's say I want to declare the type for a function which returns a key for a given object in its argument:

```
type Dimension = { x: number, y: number };

type MyFunctionGeneric1 = <T>(payload: T) => T[keyof T];
const getX1: MyFunctionGeneric1 = (payload: Dimension) => payload.x; // Doesn't work

type MyFunctionGeneric2<T> = (payload: T) => T[keyof T];
const getX2: MyFunctionGeneric2<Dimension> = (payload) => payload.x; // OK
```

My problem is that if I provide the type for the payload explicitly, then it works. However, once I try to let the generic type infer the payload type implicitly, it will complain:

```
Type '(payload: Dimension) => number' is not assignable to type 'MyFunctionGeneric1'.
  Types of parameters 'payload' and 'payload' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Dimension'
```

You can also [see it on the playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=73&pln=7&pc=69#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgWwgOwM5wPbKgXigbygA8AuKZAVwQCMIAnAGihDMpvqgF8BuAWACgBoSFACyIAGIVkAY2CZkAcRT04MgIy4oAHgAqAPgAUYAIYgANhhMATMroCUufVF0BtANYQQGAGYuAunz8MliowFAA5hDAABrqZOJSsvJYysiqGlrGZpY2ZPBIaAqOOM6mFlbWAHRE3FD1UAD0jbAYEKjIAOThAO4YdO4CQuDQidJyCmkZAEx6znjZFXkuJc5unt5+uoECIWjhUbHTCZLjKUoqdGqzBSjoWPNQi7nWq1DlLzV1Dc1QAPIAaSG-CAA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the first case doesn't work is that `MyFunctionGeneric1` describes a *generic function*, but clearly your `getX1` is not a generic function (it only accepts the Type `Dimension`), whereas in your second case, `MyFunctionGeneric2<T>`, being a generic type itself, DOES NOT describe a generic function.

If you want to make TypeScript to automatically infer `T`, you can use the following trick:

```
type Dimension = { x: number, y: number };

function infer<T>(func: MyFunctionGeneric2<T>): MyFunctionGeneric2<T> {
    return func;
}

type MyFunctionGeneric2<T> = (payload: T) => T[keyof T];
const getX2 = infer((payload: Dimension) => payload.x);  // OK
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=56&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgWwgOwM5wPbKgXigbygA8AuKZAVwQCMIAnAGihDMpvqgF8BuAWACgBAMwrIAxsEzY4yIfQA8AFQB8AChHiyAWRAAxURKkBxFPThiATEuUBKbXoOSsJ5GcvWCAqN6h0IwCjpsDTE+fk4BAVBIKB19cSdkFzcrFVwoVTAAQxAAGwwsgBMyRRtcZShFAG0AawgQDCFKgF0wsSxUYCgAc38ADQt0mTk6VUyc-KKyeCQ0KTKcCuy8gsKAOiIbMKA)

Comment: Wow, good explanation. But for ```MyFunctionGeneric1```,  isn't it what a generic used for?  You define sth generic. You can add your specific type when real application. If I really want to follow the format of what Terry wrote, what can I do? I have spent half an hour but still no luck.

Comment: That depends on your use case. In Terry's case, he really does need a generic type instead of a type for a generic function, as his function really isn't generic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I will adapt the the second approach of Terry's code. It seems make more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is my path of trying to debug this issue. What came to my mind at first place is to try add `extends {}` to type parameter (*my assumption was that T can be not only an object but also other primitive types*):

```
type MyFunctionGeneric1 = <T extends {}>(payload: T) => T[keyof T];
const getX1: MyFunctionGeneric1 = (payload: Dimension) => payload.x;
```

When I did this, it started complaining that:

```
Type '(payload: Dimension) => number' is not assignable to type 'MyFunctionGeneric1'.
  Types of parameters 'payload' and 'payload' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Dimension'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Dimension': x, y(2322)
```

So that another assumption was born. What if TypeScript can not infer it because it does not have the actual data it can use for types evaluation?

To check this assumption I made this;

```
type MyFunctionGeneric1 = <T>(payload: T) => T[keyof T];
const getX1: MyFunctionGeneric1 = (payload: Dimension) => payload.x;

getX1({x: 10, y: 20});
```

Which is changed nothing, though inferring for type when you actually called the method works as expected (*we have a data to infer from after all*).

That way we can narrow the problem to something related with TypeScript itself, not your code.

My assumption is that the difference how types are evaluated when you assigning the function and actually calling it. In your case, you are assigning a function to the variable with the type `MyFunctionGeneric` and at this step it can not infer the signature and the types. So that, when TypeScript evaluates the type `MyFunctionGeneric` it lacks type data from right-hand expression.

**How to deal with it?**

You can pass the return type explicitly, but, well, that what the question is about...

```
type Dimension = { x: number, y: number };
type Getter<T> = (payload: T) => T[keyof T]

const getX: Getter<Dimension> = (payload) => payload.x
```

P.S. I'm still trying to figure out why it can not infer, but seems like it is expected limitation from TypeScript. You are trying to narrow a generic type to non-generic.